# Why does any change made to the HTML using DevTools reset on refreshing the webpage?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I was just going through the DevTools in Chrome.
But stuck at a point.
Why does any change made to the HTML using DevTools reset on refreshing the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any changes made by developer tools inside the loaded html file is temporary and only visible inside the currently loaded html page. The original file remains unchanged. You have to change your HTML file manually to make a permanent change in them.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not editing the HTML file on the server but the one downloaded from it

The devtools are debugging tools not coding tools